# Access Camera from Google Script Website

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am facing problem to access the camera from **Google script Website.**

I have tried

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-input">
```

and

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

But both open **file manager** to choose file instead of asking for **camera permission**.

Is there any way to capture the image and upload to google drive using Google Script webapp.

I have tried Google Picker API, **But no Luck it gives me origin error**.

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? [Does it support that feature](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture)?

Comment: I have tested it on Chrome, Microsoft  Edge, Firefox.

Comment: So that's a "no" then.

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic? Any searches about accessing browser permissions - camera, microphone, location, etc - from Apps Script? Are you certain your old approach did not work, but you simply do not correctly set the iframe origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) method to trigger the authorization flow. Configure the constraints parameter to describe requested media types, e.g.

```
var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
```

Add the <video> tag to embed video & audio streams. The getUserMedia() method returns a Promise with success and failure handlers that gets resolved after user interacts with the authorization prompt.

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)

    .then(function(stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("An error has occured: " + err);
    });
  </script>
```

Please refer to the docs for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

I've tested the above in my GAS web app.